# Magento2 How to set expiration time for token

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, token

I Have generated a token for API calls by using following code :

```
curl -X POST "http://magento2.ce/rest/V1/integration/customer/token"\
-H "Content-Type:application/json"\
-d '{"username":"john@change.me", "password":"abc123"}'
```

-How to set expiry time for this token?
-Can we generate token by using username? with out password.

Comment: Is it possible we will set token lifetime to minutes..?

Answer (score 9):

Install Magento from github.com/magento/magento2.git and then use the steps from the documentation page about [Token-based authentication](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)

On Github, you should look at branch '2.2.0-preview' or 'develop' or any other that uses the codebase of 2.2.0 or higher (develop is an active branch by default).

This feature probably will be backported on Magento 2.1.9 and other versions.

Here is what it should look like:
[image: Access Token Expiration]

Comment: Thank You Tomaw...But i am using Magento2.1.6 Version. I want to disable token expiry feature in this version.
In 2.1.6 version we have "Expiration Period" option.If i am giving empty value for this field, then also token expiring after some time.

Comment: I tried to set the Customer Token Lifetime (hours) to 0 and also 48 hours, but regardless of what number I enter, the token I receive expires in 1 hour. I cleaned, flushed the cache, but the problem remains. Any ideas how to make magento realize the new settings? I'm using Magento 2.4.4.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using the Web API, you may only need to allow anonymous access for simple tasks such as fetching products for your custom frontend/client - no need for an access token. 
`Admin > Stores > Configuration > Services > Magento Web API`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can generate tokens by using the only username.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$tokenModelFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory');

$this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;    
$customerToken = $this->tokenModelFactory->create();
$tokenKey = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customerId)->getToken();

return $tokenKey;
```

Get the `$customerId` from customer collection and place it in the code at

```
$tokenKey = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customerId)->getToken();
```