# How to set Rest API oAuth token expire in minutes or seconds

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, webapi

How to set Rest API oAuth token expire in minutes or seconds in admin. Currently it's showing hours and it will not accept like 0.5(for 30 minute etc) magento2.
Any One know about this, please help me asap.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/psTPz.png

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188482/magento2-how-to-set-expiration-time-for-token
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html
Please check.

Comment: @Nits: this is show in hours I need to update token expire in minutes or seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Magento DevDocs said you can not edit this setting.

[image]

**You have one Option Also**

Step 1: Set the value as non trace able value for ex: 7856467.

Step 2: Search this value directly in DB, then edit and Save this value as 0.5

Here code is set according to hours, so if you want to set it for **15mins** then, you need to calculate with formula `n/60 = value`

```
for ex - 15/60 = 0.25.
```

> Override This file - Path : vendor\magento\module-integration\Helper\Oauth\Data.php

And Update the Value as (need to remove (int) )

```
$hours = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('oauth/access_token_lifetime/customer'); return $hours > 0 ? $hours : 0;
```

And Then Run Commands

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
```

so basically you need to do it like this

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have already installed magento2.3.2 version.
My question is that how to set Rest API oAuth token expire in minutes or seconds in admin. Currently it's showing hours and it will not accept like 0.5(for 30 minute etc).

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I need to update Admin Default Lifetime to minute, it will not work if change 0.5 from database level or direct admin aswell.

Comment: here code is set according to hours, so if you want to set it for 15mins then you need to calculate with formula n/60 = value. for ex - 15/60 = 0.25. so basically you need to do it like this

Comment: Where to mention this formula, do you know about this then please help me.

Comment: you need to calculate your value, according to your time. Please tell me what time do you want to replace ?

Comment: 30 minute, I am able to calculate the value in minutes like (30/60 = 0.50) this but I am not able to find where to mention this code, How to get admin oauth toke,
I am working on Rest Api, and generate a token http://magento.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token to generate a token and it's will give me random token, but in my code how I will do that token expire in 30 minute because magento expire time is taking 1hour..
Where to mention this formula, in which file we need to mention this and how to do.

Comment: not found in vendor/magento/framework
Clean Expired Tokens is mention inside vendor\magento\module-integration\Cron but not found where it's calculate hour wise, or where to update so it will convert to minutes.

Comment: Here is the path : vendor\magento\module-integration\Helper\Oauth\Data.php -  Function Name - getCustomerTokenLifetime()

Comment: I have updated 0 to -1 but still not work
$hours = (int)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('oauth/access_token_lifetime/customer');
        return $hours > -1 ? $hours : 0;

Comment: can you run all commands ? please run php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f

Comment: already done all commands.
I have set default value if hour is greater then 0 to 0.5 which worked prefrectly..
$hours = (int)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('oauth/access_token_lifetime/customer'); return $hours > 0 ? $hours : 0.5;

Thank you so much for help.