# Why do authentication tokens only last an hour / How can I persist a user

Tags: magento2, token, authentication

I'm using magento 2.3 in a headless way via their rest & graphql api's.

By default the auth tokens you get from magento (according to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) only last 1 hour. This means a user potentially has to authenticate multiple times in the same session and keeping a user logged in is basically impossible unless I actually store his username / password somewhere which is not safe.

Am I misunderstanding the docs / is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is more down to magento settings than GraphQL itself. 
If you have a read of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189178/68997

It states that the token is set in the configuration!